# Jupyter: suppress %%file magic output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

When using IPython's `%%file` magic to write the content of a notebook cell to a file in the current working directory, is there a way to suppress the `Created file ...` info text displayed on execution of the cell?

Sometimes creating files in this way is super handy (for example when using a Matlab kernel) but this is a huge problem with respect to version control, I don't want the structure of my local filesystem to be present in code that others work on as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source for this function

```
@cell_magic
def writefile(self, line, cell):
    """Write the contents of the cell to a file.

    The file will be overwritten unless the -a (--append) flag is specified.
    """
    args = magic_arguments.parse_argstring(self.writefile, line)
    if re.match(r'^(\'.*\')|(".*")$', args.filename):
        filename = os.path.expanduser(args.filename[1:-1])
    else:
        filename = os.path.expanduser(args.filename)

    if os.path.exists(filename):
        if args.append:
            print("Appending to %s" % filename)
        else:
            print("Overwriting %s" % filename)
    else:
        print("Writing %s" % filename)

    mode = 'a' if args.append else 'w'
    with io.open(filename, mode, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(cell)

File:   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/osm.py
```

Comment: Okay so it seems there is nothing that can be done, too bad.